# How to UPDATE everything from SELECT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I have a table called `InventoryTransfer` which contains the summary information of the inventory transfer. It looks like this:

[image]

I also have another table called `InventoryTransferDetails` which contains the items that were transferred as shown here:

[image]

I have another table that contains the current quantity of all the items which is named `Inventory`.

[image]

Now my application makes use of the `CTransferID` value to add the items into the `Inventory` table. Currently, my application first retrieves the items under `InventoryTransferDetails` and loops to add them to the `Inventory` table at application level. While it works, I know it's not very efficient.

So for `CTransferID` value `1009`, we have 2 items namely `ORQ` and `MKX`. What I would like to do is Update the values `ORQ` and `MKX` inside `Inventory` table with the quantity specified in `InventoryTransferDetails`. In this case, the final values of `ORQ` and `MKX` inside `Inventory` table would now be +18 and +8 respectively.

My logic would be similar to the statement below. This statement is just an example to demonstrate my logic.

```
UPDATE GBInventory i
SET i.CQuantity += td.CQuantity
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM GBInventoryTransferDetails) AS td
WHERE td.CTransferID = 1008 
AND i.CSite = 'Store'
AND i.CBarcode = td.CBarcode;
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: What do yo mean by "... retrieved from `SELECT` in 1 statement"? Also, which table do you want to `UPDATE`? You write `Inventory`, but there is no table with such a name in you question.

Comment: I still don't really understand it. Is your question: "How do I update `Inventory`, only using the entries which have `CSite = 'Store'` and `CTransferID = 1009`, such that `T1.CQuantity=T1.CQuantity+T2.CQuantity`"? If so, isn't the `InventoryTransfer` table irrelevant for your question? Finally, could you avoid using screenshots and insert tables into your question? (See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) how to do it.)

Comment: Hi, I am not fully understanding your question but I think you need to join the two tables and add set statement with comma separated column names.

Comment: @Jan I edited my post. I hope it's understandable now. Thank you.

Comment: @PRIN I edited my post. I hope it's understandable now. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use images use formatted text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you just need to remove the `SELECT *` line, and move the first `Inventory T1` table reference into the `FROM` using a `JOIN`

Better table aliases would be useful also.

```sql
UPDATE i
SET CQuantity += td.CQuantity
FROM Inventory i
JOIN InventoryTransferDetails td
   ON i.CBarcode = td.CBarcode
WHERE td.CTransferID = 1009 
  AND i.CSite = 'Store';
```

If you want to see the data as well, you can also add an `OUTPUT` clause.

You can also do this using a `SELECT` inside a CTE, which can often make it easier for debugging. Note that the CTE alias is updated directly, do not join or name the tables again.

```
WITH ToUpdate AS (
    SELECT
      i.*,
      NewQuantity = i.CQuantity + td.CQuantity
    FROM Inventory i
    JOIN InventoryTransferDetails td
       ON i.CBarcode = td.CBarcode
    WHERE td.CTransferID = 1009 
      AND i.CSite = 'Store'
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET CQuantity = NewCQuantity;
```

Comment: Oh my Gosh! It works! I have been doing something like this but they never worked. I have been on this for a few hours now. Before I mark this as answered, I want to ask something so I'll understand this. Usually in a single UPDATE statement we don't use FROM. In that context, what does FROM mean? I mean my mistake was that I used from with InventoryTransferDetails. I'm querying from InventoryTransferDetails so why is it FROM Inventory? Thank you so much.

Comment: It's SQL Server specific syntax to do a joined update. It avoids needing to put the joined table into both a `WHERE` subquery and a `SELECT` subquery. Note that the top line updates the alias, do not specify the full table name again.

Comment: I'm almost there. Just a little bit more. Is it possible to convert the statement to something that makes use of the SELECT, maybe it's more understandable? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking again Sir. Can you please check my post again? I edited my logic statement. It doesn't work. But why? Would you be able to explain it? I would want something like this because it's understandable to me. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: The official documentation explains the full update syntax .. I suggest taking a read

Comment: And you don't need to call anyone sir here